# append uploaded file, to new html page

Tags: php

this is the code i use in main

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <form action="welcome.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input id="foto1slct" name="foto1" size="45" type="file" value="Upload" accept="image/*">
 <input id="invia" type="submit" value="Invia">
 </input>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

i use this piece of code in welcome.php to append the uploaded file in the html

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <?php $file = 'Italia/categoria.html'; ?>
 <?php $current = file_get_contents($file); ?>
 <?php $current .= $_POST["foto1"]; ?>
 <?php file_put_contents($file, $current); ?>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

There were two errors in yours code, i fix it

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <?php
 $file = 'categoria.html';
 $fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
 $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"];
 $newfile="tempareryloc/$fileName";
 move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc,$file);
 $current = file_get_contents($file);
 $current .= file_get_contents($newfile);
 unlink($newfile);
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

now it seems it work but, it save the image in text into the created html.
could we find the solution?